# Lightroom Import - how to exclude .thumbnails folder

Tags: lightroom-4, android, import

I am importing using Lightroom 4.4.2 from an Android device.

The device generates thumbnails of the full size images and saves them in a `.thumbnails` folder inside the `DCIM` folder. LR sees this folder and imports all the thumbnails as well as the full size images.

Is there any way to make LR ignore the `.thumbnails` folder?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way to filter that specific folder, however you can disable having it look in sub-folders altogether from the options on the Import screen.

Comment: But then I would have to make several imports as there are other subfolders that I do want to import

Answer (score 1):

First of, my Lightroom (5.2) does not import `.thumbnails` or any other hidden folder. This might be Mac specific, as files starting with dot are hidden in Unix, but not in Windows.

There isn't a good option to filter out folders from import. What you could do is to import thumbnails too, and filter those out. At least with my Android phone (Nexus 5), thumbnails does not include exif metadata, which is enough to filter those for deletion.

Of course, importing and then deleting takes additional disk space (not too much; my `.thumbnails` have over 6000 files and is just 300MB). Also, having to filter and delete thumbnails after each import is cumbersome.

Here's alternative approach for Mac users (and for Windows users too, after installing additional programs): open terminal (Spotlight->Terminal, <kbd>enter</kbd>) and run:

```
rsync -a /Location/of/Android/DCIM --exclude .thumbnails ~/Pictures/Android_photos
```

Replace file paths accordingly. This will sync all files, except `.thumbnails` folder to Pictures. After that, in Lightroom import, select "Add" from top of the dialog, instead of Copy.